# What font does Super Skeleton use for its logo?

Tags: font-identification, logo

Can you tell me which font is used for the logo of this [web site](http://super-skeleton.mdnw.net/)?
How can I create my logo using the same font and same pattern?

What 's the font used for the capital text?
[image: Super Skeleton's logo]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That would be [Pacifico](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/pacifico):

[image: Pacifico Screenshot]

Open Font License, so a lot of ways it can be used.